# Create list of dynamic objects with order and columns from another list

Tags: c#, excel, linq, dynamic

i have to implement functionality that export some data of type TEST to excel. The View has a table which is fill with some data of type TEST. To make it more interesting, user could select what columns from this type T want to export.

So i cant make model for every case (maybe i need to use reflection and create classes in runtime?) because this type TEST has about 50 properties (columns).

I figured out that i can create a list of dynamic objects with selected properties (columns) but i can't imagine how i can do that.

I have a method to need to provide worksheet, list of full data model TEST and list of columns names (for excel header):

```
public static void FillSheetWithData(ExcelWorksheet ws, List<TEST> data, List<string> columns)
{

    for... [creating header]

    //create dynamic object from TEST only with properties from columns parameter
    List<dynamic> mappedData = data.???

    //fill excel with data
    ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(mappedData);
}
```

For example:

```
Main model => 

public class TEST
{
    public string Name;
    public string Title;
    public string Client;
    public decimal Price;
    public string Address;
    public string Owner;
    public DateTime Date;
    ...
}

List of columns =>

List<string> columns = new List<string>
{
    "Title",
    "Price",
    "Name",
    "Date"
};

Dynamic object should looks like => 

dynamic obj = new {
    Title = "data from main model",
    Price = "data from main model",
    Name = "data from main model",
    Date = "data from main model"
}
```

If you have some idea i will be grateful!

Comment: you mean `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` ? edit: or rather `List<ExpandoObject>` ... with `ExpandoObject` can be used as `dynamic` or as `IDictionary<string, object>`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W7xbcB

Comment: and  `List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>(); var exp = new ExpandoObject(); 
var expasdict = exp as IDictionary<string, object>;
expasdict[Title] = test.Title;
  data.Add(exp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/) for your excel manipulation.
Looking at their documentation of the [LoadFromCollection](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase/M/LoadFromCollection(T)) method there is overload which accepts `MemberInfo[]` which is used to populate only specific properties from the provided objects. This means you can reuse your full object with all properties and provide only the member info you need to export.

Something to start with:

```
var flags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public  
       | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance  
       | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty;

var memberInfos = typeof(TEST)
.GetMembers(flags)
.Where(x =>  columns.Contains(x.Name))
.ToArray();

ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromCollection(data, ..., ..., flags, memberInfos);
```

If you want to learn more about **GetMebers** and **reflection** in general there is good starting page at [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection)